# Uploading image to server using byte array to php upload in flex 4.5 air

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-upload, arrays

I'm using Flex 4.5 in a Mobile air for android application.

So, Using the Camera/Camera roll (http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/09/29/air-for-android-camera-and-camera-roll/)
I want to do a simple upload using amfphp

Note: Since this is how you get pictures on devices, i cant use the filreference because it wants you to get the pictures using "browse" which cant be done on android or ios

My plan is, after I select a picture or capture one with the camera, in the event I can get the local url to the picture that was taken like this:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110531_205113.jpg
```

I'm putting this in the `imageURL` var

(i'm assuming i should make it into a byte array to transfer it, im not exactly sure this is my first time making something like this)

Here's how i'm taking that image, making it into a byte array, and using amfphp to send the upload to the server:

```
protected function upload_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imageURL);
                var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);

                urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoaderComplete);
                urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
                urlLoader.load(request);

            }

            private function onURLLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
            {
                var byteArray:ByteArray;
                byteArray = event.target.data;

                //send upload using amfphp!
                gw.call("MyClass.uploadFile", uploadImageRes, byteArray);
            }
```

Here's my php code:

```
function uploadFile($fileData) {
        $myFilePath = '../../../assets/userphotos/imageone';
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/","_",microtime()).'_'.$fileData["filename"];
        file_put_contents($myFilePath, $fileData["filedata"]);

        //eventually add the mysql query to add the image path to mysql server

        return true;
       }
```

But i'm getting an error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion.

This is the first time im trying something like this so im not even really sure if im going about it right. All the examples I find online go about using the fileReference class, but that seems to require me to use the "browse" method, and im on a mobile application that uses the camera and camera roll to grab pictures off the device, and im not sure how to incorporate that into the fileref class. I figured i could just get the byte array and send it to php myself and it should be just fine.

My end goal is to be able to upload the image to a folder on the server, and i'll make a mysql update to put the location of the file, i'm not really worried about the mysql part yet, im sure that part will be really easy and i can figure it out. I just wanted to get some help with the actual uploading the image to a directory thing. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can at least help you with debugging this.

NetConnection.Call.BadVersion is usually thrown in the client when an error has been thrown in the php script. That makes php output the error which in turn invalidates the amf structure of the response, making flash not recognize the amf format and throw a "Bad version" error.

I recommend you get a packet capture program (like wireshark) and see what the server is outputting, or if you are only getting this error on the mobile device, make a check on the bottom of the php script with [error_get_last()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and save it in a text file that you can review.

When you see which error php is throwing maybe you can get further with this.